# Seeking Literature on coordinate transformations?

Tags: coordinate-system, algorithm, references, gis-principle, reprojection-mathematics

I am looking to hone my skills in the **theory** and the mathematicas involving the projections systems, projection transformations ( from xy to uv, φλ and vice versa).

Can you share the books/pdfs/online-references that you have read and found them useful?

Answer (score 4):

I've always referred to ["Map Projections: A Working Manual", 1987, Snyder, John P.
USGS Professional Paper: 1395](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395) which is available as a PDF to [download](http://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I liked [Datums and Map Projections: For Remote Sensing, GIS and Surveying from Jonathan IIiffe and Roger Lott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142007041X). Make sure you grab the second edition. However, it still has some errors. Nevertheless you get some examples to practice.

Answer (score 3):

More detailed and with all the information you need, the [Coordinate Conversions and Transformations including Formulas](http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/g7-2.pdf) document gives you 
a detailed explanation of the map projections and the formulas necessary for executing coordinate conversions and transformations (suported by the EPSG dataset).

Answer (score 0):

The following book is pretty good if you work in an ArcGIS environment.

[Working with Projections and Datum Transformations in ArcGIS](http://www.pointsverlag.com/buch/?tx_tlshop_pi1%5Bdo%5D=detail&tx_tlshop_pi1%5Buid%5D=15&cHash=fa52d88a964127a73cc3c16a6bce2952)

It´s a good introduction if you are new to the subject but goes into detail where necessary.